# Hadoop MapReduce (using Python) launch KeyError on Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I'm trying to process a dataframe using MapReduce. I initially created the script for the mapper and tried to run it from the local terminal, and it works correctly:

**mapper.py**

```
import sys
import string
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(sys.stdin)

#cleaning relevant fields
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], unit='s').apply(lambda x : x.year)
df['Summary'] = df['Summary'].str.lower()
df['Summary'] = df['Summary'].str.replace('[{}]'.format(string.punctuation), '')

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    key = ''
    key += str(row.iloc[7])
    key += '-'
    for word in str(row.iloc[8]).split():
        key += word
        print('{}\t{}'.format(key, 1))
        key = key.replace(word, '')
```

Then I developed the **reducer.py**:

```
import sys

current_key = None
current_count = 0
key = None

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()

    key, count = line.split('\t', 1)

    try:
        count = int(count)
    except ValueError:
        continue

    if current_key == key:
        current_count += count
    else:
        if current_key:
            print(current_key, current_count)

        current_count = count
        current_key = key

if current_key == key:
    print('{}\t{}'.format(current_key, current_count))
```

At this point I tried to run the processing over Hadoop with the following command (obviously after loading the .csv file over HDFS):

```
bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-3.1.0.jar \
-file /mypath/mapper.py    -mapper 'python /mypath/mapper.py' \
-file /mypath/reducer.py   -reducer 'python /mypath/reducer.py' \
-input /user/andreone/input/Reviews.csv -output /user/andreone/output/out_1
```

But I get the following error:

```
[...]
2018-05-11 17:46:03,706 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
2018-05-11 17:46:03,983 INFO streaming.PipeMapRed: R/W/S=1000/0/0 in:NA [rec/s] out:NA [rec/s]
2018-05-11 17:46:04,039 INFO streaming.PipeMapRed: R/W/S=10000/0/0 in:NA [rec/s] out:NA [rec/s]
2018-05-11 17:46:04,793 INFO streaming.PipeMapRed: R/W/S=100000/0/0 in:100000=100000/1 [rec/s] out:0=0/1 [rec/s]
2018-05-11 17:46:05,721 INFO streaming.PipeMapRed: R/W/S=200000/0/0 in:100000=200000/2 [rec/s] out:0=0/2 [rec/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2525, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 117, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 139, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1265, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Time'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[....]
```

It seems as if he did not find the key 'Time'. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you sure the column 'Time' exists?

Comment: Yes. On the local terminal I modified the script to print the first 5 lines of the dataframe after reading it with sys.sdtin and it's all correct

Comment: So `'Time' in df.columns` returns `True`?

Comment: Yes it does. To do these tests I'm launching the file from the terminal with the command cat Reviews.csv | python mapping.py, I'm not running the code over HDFS

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the late answer, but I solved this today (after finding your question here) by simply renaming the columns the exact same names:

```
# Read the data to a Pandas Dataframe
inputDataCSV = pandas.read_csv(sys.stdin, dtype={"Date/Time" : object, "Lat" : object, "Lon" : object, "Base" : object}, encoding='ascii')
# Rename columns
inputDataCSV.columns = ['Date/Time', 'Lat', 'Lon', 'Base']
```

This my first post ever.  I hope it helps someone.